# Unable to canonicalize address in EKS Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, dns, amazon-eks, kube-dns

I set up two pods using the same operator code in Kubernetes. When trying to connect to a zookeeper pod, one of them gives the error (broker pod):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Unable to canonicalize address tiny-cluster-zk-0.tiny-cluster-zk:2181 because it's not resolvable
```

The other pod is able to resolve

```
2021-06-07T18:06:59,476 INFO [main-SendThread(tiny-cluster-zk-0.tiny-cluster-zk:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - 
Socket connection established to tiny-cluster-zk-0.tiny-cluster-zk/172.xx.yyy.zzz:2181, initiating session
```

When I exec into the working pod, and run the ping command, this is what I see:

```
ping tiny-cluster-zk-0.tiny-cluster-zk
PING tiny-cluster-zk-0.tiny-cluster-zk (172.31.248.114): 56 data bytes
```

If I replace it with the resolved IP, that too works

```
ping 172.xx.yyy.zzz
PING 172.xx.yyy.zzz (172.xx.yyy.zzz): 56 data bytes
```

But on the buggy pod (broker pod), ping to the zookeeper service does not work

```
ping tiny-cluster-zk-0.tiny-cluster-zk
ping: bad address 'tiny-cluster-zk-0.tiny-cluster-zk'
```

And if I replace the name with the IP, it works

```
ping 172.xx.yyy.zzz
PING 172.xx.yyy.zzz (172.xx.yyy.zzz): 56 data bytes
```

It seems that the name is not getting resolved.
I tried following the steps present in the doc: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/
,
still no solution.

```
kubectl exec -i -t druid-tiny-cluster-brokers-0 -- nslookup kubernetes.default
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

command terminated with exit code 1
```

Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: I did not see any difference.

Comment: Please include your deployment manifest or the source, so community can try to replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that one of the nodes of which the pods were scheduled did not have the correct policies. Hence connectivity issues. Fixed that, and the all the processes were able to communicate with each other